# zend framework 2 get table instace from entity

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm new to zf2 and i'm having some difficulties getting used to the way it works.

basically i'm trying to get an instance of the table handler from an entity

In this example (we have a

```
namespace Album\Model;

class Album
{
public $id;
public $artist;
public $title;

    public function exchangeArray($data)
    {
        $this->id     = (isset($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : null;
        $this->artist = (isset($data['artist'])) ? $data['artist'] : null;
        $this->title  = (isset($data['title'])) ? $data['title'] : null;
    }
}
```

And a tableGetaway

```
namespace Album\Model;

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class AlbumTable
{
    protected $tableGateway;

    public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
    {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    public function fetchAll()
    {
        $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();
        return $resultSet;
    }

    public function getAlbum($id)
    {
        $id  = (int) $id;
        $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(array('id' => $id));
        $row = $rowset->current();
        if (!$row) {
            throw new \Exception("Could not find row $id");
        }
        return $row;
    }

     public function saveAlbum(Album $album)
     {
        $data = array(
            'artist' => $album->artist,
            'title'  => $album->title,
        );

       $id = (int)$album->id;
       if ($id == 0) {
          $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
       } else {
            if ($this->getAlbum($id)) {
                $this->tableGateway->update($data, array('id' => $id));
            } else {
                throw new \Exception('Form id does not exist');
            }
        }
    }

    public function deleteAlbum($id)
    {
        $this->tableGateway->delete(array('id' => $id));
    }
}
```

and after using ServiceManager to configure the table gateway and inject into the AlbumTable we can put this function in the controller

```
public function getAlbumTable()
{
    if (!$this->albumTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->albumTable = $sm->get('Album\Model\AlbumTable');
    }
    return $this->albumTable;
}
```

so we can do stuff like

```
public function indexAction(){
    $albums = $this->getAlbumTable()->fetchAll();
    return array('albums' => $albums);
}
```

i find this very redundant because this way if we have another controller we have to redeclare the getAlbumTable function again

**My question is** is there a way to get an instance of the table from the entity Album

something like

```
$album = new Album();
$album->getTable()->findAll();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually do not need this `getAlbumTable()` function at all. This is mainly done to clean up the code a little bit but quite frankly: not required at all. You can simply set up your actions accessing the ServiceManager on their own:

```
public function overviewAction() { // very minified
    $table = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Album\Model\AlbumTable');
    return array('albums' => $table->fetchAll());
}
```

The advantage with separating this is mainly done for the purpose of forwarding to another action in between one request. In this case the `ServiceLocator` won't be called a 2nd time.

Your approach would make the code a little bit fuzzy. As there would be no clean separation between your Model and Mapper. The `Album`-Model should be nothing but a `Data-Object`